# Kotlin Queue returning object

Tags: android, kotlin, queue

I am trying to create a queue of List

so far I have this

```
var queue = LinkedList<Array<IntArray>>()
queue.add(arrayOf(intArrayOf(1,2,0)))
queue.add(arrayOf(intArrayOf(3,4,5)))
Log.d("debugVal",queue.poll()[0].toString())
```

It returns something like this

```
D/debugVal: [I@81fc7ad
```

I was expecting it to print 1

I think it's returning an object. Can someone please tell me how to retrieve the list values from the polled element
I need all three of the values from each polled element

Comment: Which result do you expect? A string like "debugVal: 2, 2, 1" ?

Comment: I have edited and explained the expected result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element returned with the method `queue.poll()` is a `Array<IntArray>`, not an `IntArray`. When you call `queue.poll()[0]` you are getting the first element of that `Array<IntArray>`, so an `IntArray`. If you want to get the first element of the `IntArray`, you should call `queue.poll()[0][0]`:

```kotlin
var queue = LinkedList<Array<IntArray>>()
queue.add(arrayOf(intArrayOf(1, 2, 0)))
queue.add(arrayOf(intArrayOf(3, 44, 10)))
Log.d("debugVal", queue.poll()[0][0].toString())
```

Furthermore, since you said you expected it to print `3`, remember that `poll()` removes the first element, not the last one. If you want to remove the last one, you can call `pollLast()` instead of `poll()`.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like i was putting an Array of Array in the queue

the correct code should be

```
var queue = LinkedList<Array<Int>>()
queue.add(arrayOf(1,2,0))
queue.add(arrayOf(3,4,5))
Log.d("alpha",queue.poll()[0].toString())
```

Now I am getting 1 as expected